# C# - Start Pie Chart Values at the Top of the Pie

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

okay so I have this task to make a chart, that would start the data horizontally.
Meaning 90degrees to the right(always). same as this in the picture below.

[image]

[image]

is this even possible? I accomplish the above picture using:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Rotation = 90;
```

but the problem is it only works for two data. Other than the 2 data, the pie rotates to its desired behaviour. Like in this image below. which produces 5 data in the chart.

[image]

**UPDATE**

In simple terms I would like to achieve [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713975.aspx).

Comment: Pie charts suck. Use a horizontal bar chart. Much better data viz.

Comment: @teylyn well. it is not a requirement so... Its useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky me! i found the answer with my curiosity.

For the sake of those who are also facing this problem. So the easy answer I was looking for was

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Rotation = -90;
```

**NOTE:** 
`Rotation` accept values up until 180 range only.
Because i had this exception error when i tried to put a `270` value.

> Exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   System.Web.DataVisualization.dll, but did not handle in the user code
>
> Additional Information: angle of rotation must be specified in the
>   range of -180 to 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a57eb7cb-7173-40cd-888d-699d4d99c428/starting-pie-chart-from-12-oclock-position-not-3-oclock?forum=MSWinWebChart) if your chart is not using 3D styles:

```
c.Series["s1"]["PieStartAngle"] = "270"
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is actually available. On Form.cs (design window) right click on the chart and click properties.

```
then go to Series->Custom Properties->PieStartAngle.
```

It's default 0 and it looks like 90. When you change it to 270 your problem will solve.

Btw, you **can't** write it like

`chart1.Series[0].CustomProperties.PieStartAngle = 270;`

You only can edit from the design window.